# (Linear combinations) Algebra of translated radial test functions [Radial basis functions]

Tags: smoothness

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Function $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ shall be called translated radial function if there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g \colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall y \in \Omega$ we have $f(y) = g( \| x - y \|)$, where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. Let $P( \Omega)$ denote the family of all linear combinations of translated radial functions on $\Omega$ which are test functions, that is, they are $C^\infty$ smooth and of compact support.

I wasn't able to find any papers which studied the properties of $P(\Omega)$, though that is probably due to the fact that I'm not familiar with terminology that might've already been coined.

My questions are:

1. If this family has already been studied (probably it was, I think), where should I look for papers regarding it?
2. I'm especially interested in whether $P(\Omega)$ is dense in $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, the family of smooth functions with compact support with topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives on compact sets.
3. If the answer to previous questions is true, I'm also interested in whether one can use a different norm (or even metric) to define what radial function means here and still have mentioned density.

---

As J.J. Green pointed out, the name I was looking for was "radial basis fuctions".

Thanks to this comment I also realized that while it still would be very interesting to have some density results in the family $P(\Omega)$, I could change my initial questions so that it would allow not only linear combinations, but also pointwise multiplication of functions.

Therefore, let $R(\Omega)$ denote the algebra constructed from elements of $P(\Omega)$ by adding the operation of pointwise multiplication. With this change added, I'd still be interested whether:

4. Family $R(\Omega)$ is dense in $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$,
5. Norm used to define what "radial" means could be changed.

Comment: "Raidial basis functions" is the name you're looking for, there's a big theory on them

Comment: In distribution theory one uses a standard approximation by convolution with *bump functions*, and a common choice is $\varphi(x)=c\exp(-1/(1-\|x\|^2))$ for $\|x\|< 1$and $0$ for $\|x\|\ge 1$ where $c$ is chosen to make $\int\varphi(x)dx=1$, and 
scaled versions $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)=\varepsilon^{-n}\varphi(\varepsilon x)$.

Convolution means averaging translates of such functions, and these averages are limits of finite linear combinations. Thus, the linear span of translates of all $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is dense in many spaces of distribution theory.